# Jenkins pipeline: cannot get jobs to run in pipeline with propagate

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing my first Jenkins pipeline. Its basic goal for now is just to sequentially run a bunch of jobs in a pipeline, to which I will later add different functionality. I am trying to use `propagate: false` so I can handle specific failures myself, instead of the pipeline exiting with an error as soon as a job fails. Note that in the code snippet I'm showing 2 different approaches I've tried (job a and job b. In reality there are about a dozen jobs) that basically return the same stacktrace. I'm stumped. If I try it in the pipeline's script box, it works. But if I do it in the `jenkinsfile` I get an error.

EDIT: forgot to mention - jenkins version - 2.7.4

### Code:

```
#!groovy
def SUCCESS_LIST =  ["SUCCESS", "UNSTABLE"]
stage "Unit Tests"
node ('k8s'){
    echo 'Running unit tests..'
    currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    a = build job 'Some Unit Tests', propagate: false
    b = build("Other System Unit Tests"), propagate: false

    jobsList<Object> = [a, b]

    // check if there was a failure. if so - mark job as 'failed'.
    for (job in jobsList){
        if (!SUCCESS_LIST.contains(job.result)) {
            //currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
            mail to: amos@company_mail.com, subject: 'The Pipeline failed at unit-tests'
        }
    }   
}
```

### stacktrace:

```
Started by user Amos B
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/my-company/companyone.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/my-company/companyone.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.username automation@my-company.com # timeout=10
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git6347898027159980380.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/my-company/companyone.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 5d349a17a9ee89d340b63db92a71e159780ea7ad (refs/remotes/origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 5d349a17a9ee89d340b63db92a71e159780ea7ad
 > git rev-list 65a8a33381ae18a1aefdd57a7d64fd3a475407fb # timeout=10
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: expecting '}', found ',' @ line 8, column 49.
   ild job 'Knowledge Unit Tests', propagat
                                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:237)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:167)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:410)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:373)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:213)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

It's the exact same error no matter which syntax (a or b) is used. what am I missing?

Comment: For starters, you define a variable `SUCESS_LIST` but then use `SUCCESS_LIST` in your `if` statement.

Comment: @Jacob Not the problem but - thanks for catching what would turn out to be a problem later on :) Corrected in my code and ran it even though I had no doubt that wasn't the actual cause. Appreciate the catch anyway!

Comment: Good to know. So, I've called other jobs in two different ways that you haven't tried. Perhaps your lack of colon after `job` is causing it to throw the error about the missing `}`?

`build job: 'job-name'`
`build 'job-name'`

Comment: @jacob yes! that was it. I wish you had written an answer that I could accept :)

Comment: I just added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this to call other jobs from your pipeline. The lack of a colon after `job` is throwing the error:

`build job: 'job-name'`